# How do I deactivate the pop-up flash on the Nikon D7000 when using a hotshoe flash?

Tags: nikon-d7000, popup-flash

How do I deactivate the pop-up flash on the Nikon D7000 when using a flash unit that is mounted in the hot-shoe?

Comment: If your hotshoe flash is on, then the pop-up flash is automatically overridden, is it not?

Comment: If the camera detects it, yes. Some third party flashes might not be detected.

Comment: What flash unit are you using with the D7000? What shooting mode is your camera set to?

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if custom setting e3 is set to **commander mode**. If so the camera thinks you want to use the pop up flash to control slave units. You need to change the mode to any of the other options: TTL, Manual, or Repeating. This is covered on page 223 of your [owner's manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/kie88335f7869dfuejdl=-cww2/D7000_EN.pdf).

If that is not it, make sure the external flash in powered on, and that it is compatible with your camera. *If the D7000 does not detect it and the camera is in a mode that activates flash automatically it will pop up the built in flash.* Even if the camera doesn't detect the external flash it should still trigger it but you will have to choose a mode that doesn't automatically activate the built in flash. **Try one of the PSAM modes.** *Since you're going to need to set the flash power manually in this case, you might find Manual mode will allow you the most control.* You might also want to turn off Auto ISO sensitivity since the camera won't know the flash is going to fire.

**If you are using a third party flash, be sure the trigger voltage of the flash is not higher than your camera can accept or you could permanently damage the electronics of your camera.** See the answers and links to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29950/can-using-an-old-flash-damage-a-new-dslr-if-it-never-fired/29978#29978).

Answer (score 1):

1. If the built-in flash has popped up, push it back down.  With a hotshoe flash attached, it generally should stay down.
2. If it pops back up, then try P, A, S, or M modes.  It should not pop up automatically in these modes.
3. Still pops back up?  You have the option of using the No Flash exposure mode

   [image]
4. Failing that, as Michael Clark suggested, check the commander mode settings and turn the flash off there.

Answer (score 0):

Well the pop up can be deactivated even in automatic mode by pushing and holding down down the flash button on the left side of the lens and rotating the back command dial to non flash. But it works only for one at the time in that mode.

Answer (score -1):

Turn your Mode dial to the Flash icon with the line through it.

Comment: Is this really the only mode in which the pop-up flash will not fire even when a hotshoe flash is mounted?